# Video Conversion - Java Audio Video Encoder (JAVE)

Tags: java, encode, jave

I am Working on MAC OS X.
I am Trying to Encode videos from one format to another Using jave ( java audio video converter) . But i keep getting this exception

it.sauronsoftware.jave.EncoderException:   Stream #0.0, 25.00 fps(r): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 608x288

So i checked where the exception is arising..
I found the code part which throws exception but Not able to resolve why this exception is coming..

the code part is:

```
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (step == 0) {
                if (line.startsWith("WARNING: ")) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.message(line);
                    }
                } else if (!line.startsWith("Output #0")) {
                    throw new EncoderException(line);
                }
```

I keep getting the Encoder exception.. The source file for Encoder.java can be found here :
http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/download.php

Comment: Without knowing anything about jave, this looks like reading of some sort of configuration file. The code that throws the exception is expecting something specific at the start of the line, and when it is not found, throws the exception. Are you using the correct configuration format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Xuggler library](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).

I think is better than JAVE on MAC OS X